# Vertical-Align not working

Tags: css

Please do not mark this as a duplicate as i have got all of the correct code (as far as i can see) in and i think something is somehow over riding it.  Used Chrome Inspector but it isnt picking up any problems.

I am trying to vertically align the text in the boxes (i dont want to id them all separately and pad them as if the text needs updated then so will the css).

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.draggable{ 
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:#EE3C96;       
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    height:90px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="draggable">
        Lost time - employee absence
        </div>

        <div class="draggable2">
        "Safe Place" to work
        </div>

        <div class="draggable">
        Lost resources - employees leaving
        </div>

        <div class="draggable">
        Financial penalties
        </div>
```

And here it is on Codepen:

http://codepen.io/lbarnes/pen/vkrib

draggable and draggable2 are essentially the same (need them separate as it is used in the jQuery :)

Thanks in advance, hopefully someone can find something as i have tried everything lol!!

Comment: When using table-cell there should have a parent whose display is table in order for the vertical alignment to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the double span tip to vertically align your multiline text.

**[First, a simple exemple](http://codepen.io/zessx/pen/HBxnG)**

And now, adapted to your needs :

```
<div class="draggable">
    <span><span>
        Lost time - employee absence
    </span></span>
</div>

<div class="draggable2">
    <span><span>
        "Safe Place" to work
    </span></span>
</div>
```

You can keep your current HTML markup, and add these spans via jQuery (I won't recommend it) :

```
$('.draggable, .draggable2').contents().wrap('<span><span></span></span>');
```

Then, add this CSS to get your vertical alignment :

```
/* Vertical align */
.draggable, .draggable2 {
    display: block;
    width: 90px; height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
.draggable>span, .draggable2>span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
}
.draggable>span>span, .draggable2>span>span {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

### [**Your CodePen forked**](http://codepen.io/zessx/pen/tFBuD)

[image]

Comment: WooHoo!! - thanks, that is working a treat.  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to  the draggable classes to solve the issue.Remove the `display:table-cell`

```
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
```

This would center the text inside the `div` both horizontally and vertically

This works for webkit browsers.For Mozilla

```
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;
```

and IE

```
    display:-ms-box;
    -ms-box-pack:center;
    -ms-box-align:center;
```

More info on [browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: what's the browser support for that?

Comment: Sorry.I forgot to mention the same.it works in all webkit browsers.For mozilla you have to add moz prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text in the box between `<p></p>` tag than add in your css the following lines:

```
.draggable p {vertical-align: middle;}
.draggable2 p {vertical-align: middle;}
```